# Block POST requests via S3 + CloudFlare?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I'm using an S3 bucket to host a static site, and CloudFlare as a CDN. 
I'm noticing a large amount of POST requests (seems like spamming attempts), and I'm trying to block them so that I don't have to pay for that traffic.

Is there a way to block all POST requests on Bucket Policy (that would be the best choice probably)? Perhaps a way to block POST requests on CloudFlare?

Comment: Data Transfer IN To Amazon S3 is free: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/. If you're concerned w/the number of POST req.s instead, they cost ~ $5 / 1M requests.

Comment: If the requests are coming from other domains, you can try a CORS config which denies all POST.

Comment: CRS config on S3? This would be very helpful as the number of requests is increasing exponentially

Comment: Some examples are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Are requests that are blocked by CORS still billable?

Comment: I couldn't find that out from AWS pages (or Google). I guess you'll need to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare has a [firewall app](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171266-How-do-I-block-blacklist-or-trust-whitelist-visitors-by-IP-) you can use to whitelist or blacklist IPs, IP ranges or countries. There doesn't seem to be a way to set rules based on HTTP request type so see if you can blacklist the IP addresses instead.

Check if you have anything listed already on the [Threat Control](https://www.cloudflare.com/threat-control) dashboard. In theory it should already challenge suspicious requests.

Comment: I'm afraid this is coming from different IPs and I don't want to block the IPs entirely, just the POST requests

Comment: Clearly it's not ideal, as they can change too. S3 doesn't seem to have anything useful either (`aws:SourceIp` or `aws:Referer` which is not reliable).